# Как вы относитесь к слову "капец"?

Tags: просторечия

Для меня оно очень уж хулиганское. А какие ассоциации вызывает у вас?

Answer (score 1):

В словаре ненормативной лексики оно обозначено как **груб-прост.** Обозначает конец, гибель, смерть.

"*Он повернул короб радиостанции и охнул: в ней зияла рваная дыра. Прохоров растерянно посмотрел по сторонам.  Капец... Сидим без связи*" (С. Дышев, Да воздастся...).

О происхождении и области употребления можно посмотреть на этом ресурсе (разные мнения):

[Откуда взялось слово - копец? | bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1110930-otkuda-vzjalos-slovo-kopec.html)

Answer (score 0):

Никак не отношусь. )))

Насчет этимологии. Помимо "капут" и "конец" (уже более далекое фонетическое) есть слово "копчик", весьма плотно ассоциирующийся с "конец" и возможно родственное "скопец", скопить". От копчика до копца один шаг - и тот короткий.

Еще версия. копец < коптец < коптить. Копчение - с дымом - всегда ассоциировалось с чем-то незавидным, марающим или метящим (по типу "черной метки").